# Rails: define column names to model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, model

I have an existing database(Postgresql). How can i create models from it? How can i pass column names for Rails? As if something like this:

Person:

Name :table_name_for_name_attribute
Surname :table_name_for_surname_attribute
PersonalCode :table_name_for_perconal_code_attribute

Unfortunately, my database is not following Rails convention, because not all tables are named in English. Any ideas how can i map it?

**UPDATE** reverse_scaffold script generates only model, but i need controller and view forms also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a table name not matching the model's using the `table_name` method.

```
class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
    def self.table_name
        'my_table_name'
    end
end
```

Change the value of 'my_table_name' to your effective table name.

For generating controllers and views with automatic methods to create, update, delete and view database objects, you should create a scaffold. There's some pretty good documentation on the [rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#getting-up-and-running-quickly-with-scaffolding) about that.

Comment: Ok, if found out, that in old Rails it was possible to define just table name, and scaffold would generate all attributes according to table`s columns. Now it is impossible. You should define all columns by yourself. Just done it so. Thank`s for your advice with self.table_name. I`ll use this approach next time.

Answer (score 1):

In your model, you'll need to tell ActiveRecord what the table name and primary key field column is named if they don't follow the conventions.

```
class MyLegacyTable < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "some_name"
  self.primary_key = "some_name_primary_key_field"
end
```

Once you've done that, ActiveRecord knows the `some_name_primary_key_field` as `id`, which makes life much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Rails doesn't need to know the column names it figures them out when it connects to the database.

As others have said you can specify a table name in the model.

As for generating controllers/views, you're pretty much own your own. script/generate scaffold is deprecated. It still works as far as creating things, but you need to pass all column names and times on the command line.

Instead have a look at the [ActiveScaffold Plugin](http://activescaffold.com/), it has a similar end result. But is much more robust and easier to adapt to model changes.